# Video Color Replacement that changes

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor

So Blender might not be the right program for this but it's my current video editing platform so I'm hoping I can do this all in one place. Basically what I'm trying to do is have a video of myself wearing a red face mask but the mask changes from a lighter to darker red depending on my speaking. I've done this before on actual models by changing emission levels with the f curves of a sound file and was hoping I could do this with a video. Thanks again!

Comment: There is no easy way to do that. Some Keying Compositing nodes like Chroma Key may help but it depends on your video lighting conditions. The best result you'll get by creating an animated mask of the parts you want to color correct using the Movie Clip Editor, but it takes some time and skills to do that accurately. Maybe if you post a few frames of your (test) video new suggestions could be offered.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to use sound's f-curve as factor for color change (darker-brighter red) in video-sequence-editor (VSE) or in compositor?

Comment: @vklidu I think that's exactly what I'm looking for, if it's possible

Comment: What stoped you to use the same sound curve? Since you already know how to color your red mask by curve what is your issue to reuse this technique for footage? Sounds to me the same. I can check that tomorrow, but would be helpful if you can extend your post about some details what you have tried and where you failed. Screens of setup or simplified blend with a sample and some mockup or sketch of desired result ... It can speed up delivery and attract more people here to answer.

Answer (score 0):

From currently given info it is hard to say how do you need to color your video. VSE doesnt support keyframing RGB CUrve modifier, so if you need that kind of modification you should use compositor.

In this example I animate Opacity of Color strip by sound's f-curve.
To do that, select the Color strip create a keyframe for Opacity (doesnt matter at what frame or what value) and under *Graph Editor* go to *Key* > **Bake sound to F-Curve**

[image]

There are other methods or addon, that you can copy&paste to where ever you need ... you just need to set the first keyframe for such parametr so f-curve is generated, than copied curve can be pasted.

[image]

[image]

If this is not your case -add more info or mockup of desired result (like I asked in comment already). This is the reason why did I vote to close your Q ... we need to know more.